# Equation for likelihood in logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression, probability

I read the likelihood is defined in logistic regression as the probability
$$
L(w) = P(y|x, w) = \prod P(y^i| x^i,w) = \prod (\sigma(z^i))^{y^i}(1-\sigma(z^i))^{(1-y^i)}
$$
and the log of the last equation is:

$$
log(L(w)) = \sum y^i log((\sigma(z^i)) + (1-y^i)log(1-\sigma(z^i))
$$

I understand (independent probabilities)
$$
L(w) = P(y|x, w) = \prod P(y^i| x^i,w)
$$
and I understand that from 
$$
L(w) = \prod (\sigma(z^i))^{y^i}(1-\sigma(z^i))^{(1-y^i)}
$$
the log is (basic log properties)
$$
log(L(w)) = \sum y^i log((\sigma(z^i)) + (1-y^i)log(1-\sigma(z^i))
$$
However, how do I get 
$$
\prod P(y^i| x^i,w) = \prod (\sigma(z^i))^{y^i}(1-\sigma(z^i))^{(1-y^i)}
$$
This basically means that
$$
P(y| x,w) = (\sigma(z))^{y}(1-\sigma(z))^{(1-y)}
$$
and I just don't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of the logistic regression model $\mathrm P(y = 1 | x,w) = \sigma\left(\left<w, x\right>\right)$ thus $\mathrm P(y = 0 | x,w) = 1- \sigma\left(\left<w, x\right>\right)$

You should be able to verify (by setting y=0/y=1) that this is equivalent to

$\mathrm P(y | x,w) = \sigma\left(\left<w, x\right>\right)^y \left[ 1- \sigma \left( \left<w, x \right> \right) \right]^{1-y}$

I think you understand the rest?

Comment: Yes, I see, it is just  a way to compact everything into a single expression.